# DrawToBitmap: Temporarily scale a control

Tags: vb.net, winforms, controls, drawtobitmap

I am using DrawToBitmap to generate a snapshop of a WinForms control and I give the user the option to generate this image in different sizes. My code for resizing the control is

```
Private Function GetChartScaledImage(NewSize As Size) As Bitmap
    Dim bmp As New Bitmap(NewSize.Width, NewSize.Height) 'Create output bitmap
    With workingChart
        Dim oldsize As Size = .Size 'Save chart's old size
        Dim lastdock As DockStyle = .Dock 'Save chart's old docking style
        .SuspendLayout()
        .Dock = DockStyle.None 'Disable dock to allow resize
        .Size = NewSize 'Set the temporary size
        .DrawToBitmap(bmp, New Rectangle(0, 0, NewSize.Width, NewSize.Height)) 'Draw the image
        .Dock = lastdock 'Recreate the old behaviour
        .Size = oldsize 'Recreate the old size
        .ResumeLayout()
    End With
    Return bmp
End Function
```

Mostly this works fine, but there is the problem that the control's size can be overridden by its parent container. I am using TableLayoutPanels that can prevent the control from being scaled properly.

Another problem I have not encountered yet but can probably happen is that the docking order of a form can be shuffled by temporarily resetting the `.Dock` property.

Is there any other way to scale the control for one paint event?

I could scale the bitmap afterwards, but that makes the image blurry. It is also not an option to create a temporary new control with the same properties, since the control is rather complicated.

Comment: I doubt you'll be able to find the universal solution.  You'd be much ahead by keeping *another* chart control around, one you feed with data and properties that are the same as the one on the UI but is not otherwise visible.   Also permits doing things that are not possible by resizing existing controls, like making the bitmap big enough to look good when printed on paper.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. It unfortunately isn't only one chart I have, and therefore always using two charts isn't really an option for me. I was hoping that there was some hidden trick to accomplish it. I guess I have another argument for ditching this forsaken control (even if it is not its fault in this case ;-)) and drawing my own.